# Forms fields filtering issue in Magento 1.8.1.0

Tags: magento, magento-1.8

In account form fields or user registration page form fields for First name and Last name, when i place the following JS code :

```
<script>alert("Here")</script>
```

It is saved and is run on page load. This is very strange, because i checked the template files and values are escaped as below:

```
<?php echo $this->escapeHtml($this->getObject()->getFirstname()) ?>
```

I have also confirmed if i am in correct template file by changing the label of field. 
I have read the following questions and tried to used them but did not worked for me.

https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/569/how-to-escape-output-data

https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/8179/is-there-a-generic-way-i-can-apply-input-filtering-to-magento-form-processing

Regarding to the observer method, it works, but when i try to login to magento admin, i cant, but when iremove the observer, i can login again.

Check the two attached screenshots.

[image: Form fields where i entered js code]

[image: The alert message from the entered js code in the field]

Kindly help me with this issue.

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have created an observer. For login forms at admin and front end (and may be some other forms), the form fields for user name and password are in array format like below:

```
<input type="text" id="username" name="login[username]" value="" class="required-entry input-text">

<input type="password" id="login" name="login[password]" class="required-entry input-text" value="">
```

TO fix this issue, i have modified the code in observer as below:

```
 public function sanitizeParams($observer)
{
    if(!Mage::app()->getStore()->isAdmin())
    {
        $post = Mage::app()->getRequest()->getParams();
        foreach($post as $pkey => $pvalue)
        {
            if(is_array($post[$pkey]))
            {
                foreach($post[$pkey] as $key => $value)
                {
                    $post[$pkey][$key] = filter_var($value, FILTER_SANITIZE_SPECIAL_CHARS);
                }
            }
            else
            {
                $post[$pkey] = filter_var($pvalue, FILTER_SANITIZE_SPECIAL_CHARS);
            }
        }

        $_POST = $post;
    }
}
```

And it fixed my problem, and is working fine now.

Thanks.